# Grab date, add hours and pass to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net

When a user clicks a Submit button, I want the code to grab the date to a Calendar control (The Ajax Control Toolkit one), convert it to DateTime and then add 17 hours so that it then places the date as selected and time as 5pm into a SQL database but I can't seem to get it right.  I have a OnClick event in my code behind with the following code:

```
string dd = Convert.ToDateTime(DueDate);
DueDate.Text = dd.AddHours(17);
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?  I thought that the text in the Calendar control would be a string?  It inputs it into a TextBox control.  VS is telling me that I cannot implicitly convert it from a TextBox to String, and from DateTime to string.  Below is what I have in my aspx file.  Nothing special, very basic.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DueDate" runat="server" TabIndex="6"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="DueDate" />
```

Once that's done, the final part of adding it to SQL will be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dd = Convert.ToDateTime(DueDate.Text);
DueDate.Text = dd.AddHours(17).ToString();
```

The first error (TextBox to string) is because you were passing in the control and trying to get a string out.

Then `dd.AddHours` wouldn't exist, because `String` doesn't have an `AddHours` method.  And lastly *datetime to string* because `DueDate.Text` expects a string, and you were using a `DateTime`

Comment: That was it.  Thanks for that.  At least I was on the right track!